# Hacer una redirección después de llenar un formulario PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, formularios, email

Hola amigos estoy intentando hacer una redirección después de haber llenado un formulario de contacto y este envía los valores a una base de datos en `MySQL`, enviando un *mail* de recordatorio al usuario de atención a clientes cuando llenan este formulario.

**Pero no me hace la redirección a la thank you page que quiero que vaya después de ser llenado.**

Me pueden ayudar este es mi código que estoy usando:

```
<?php 

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
        $servername = 'localhost';
        $username = 'localhost_db';
        $password = '';
        $db = 'contactos';

        $actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "INSERT INTO clientes_website (name,email,phone,center,url) VALUES ('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[phone]','$_POST[centros]','$actual_link')";
             if ($conn->query($sql)) {

                 $to = "contatoweb@dominio.com";
                 $asunto = 'Contacto desde sitio web';
                 $msg = "Nombre: $_POST[name] \r\nEmail: $_POST[email] \r\nTeléfono: $_POST[phone] \r\nCentro: $_POST[centros]\r\n\n";
                 mail($to, $asunto, $msg, "from: no-reply@dominio.com") or die("Error!");
                 echo "se guardo"; 
                 header("Location: http://www.dominio.com.mx/thank-u.php");
             }
             else{
                 echo "Error en el servidor";
             }

             $conn = null;    
         }
         catch(PDOException $e) {
             echo $e->getMessage();
         }
    }

?>
```

Al dar *click* se refresca la pagina y la vuelve a cargar en vez de ir a la thank you page.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola amigo ¿Qué dirección tienes en el action del formulario?

Comment: No tengo ninguna dirección en el action=""

Answer (score 0):

El problema, creo que está en que estas pintando contenido, antes de hacer el redireccionador, te recomendaría que pusieras en comentarios todas las funciones que muestren un texto en pantalla, como el `echo` o los `or die("...")` que están antes de el `header("Location: ...");` y pruebes si con esto funciona.

Comment: No funciona comente todos los **echo** y el **or die** y lo unico que hace es recargar la página y no redireccionarla.